# Aligning dataGrid and dataTable in dataGrid

Tags: css, jsf, datagrid, datatable, richfaces

I am using RichFaces 4.3.6. I have a dataGrid composed of dataGrid and dataTable.
How can I align to the top inner dataGrid and dataTable ?
vertical-align: top doesn’t work.
I would like also center the images contained in dataGrid. They are vertically centered but not horizontally. How can I do that ?
[Here a picture to show what I want](http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/questionforum.php)

```
<rich:panel> 
            <rich:dataGrid  value="#{isb.bloc.groups}" var="group" columns="#{isb.bloc.groupsSize}" styleClass="data-grid" >
                            <rich:dataGrid value="#{group.items}" var="item" columns="#{group.colNumber}" elements="#{group.itemsSize}" styleClass="data-grid">  
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{group.name}" class="facet-datagrid"></h:outputText>
                                </f:facet>
                                <rich:panel>
                                    <h:graphicImage value="/img/#{item.image.id}/#{item.image.type}" width="#{item.image.width}" height="#{item.image.height}" class="image" />    
                                </rich:panel>
                            </rich:dataGrid>

                            <h:dataTable value="#{group.remarks}" var="rem" styleClass="data-table">
                                <h:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText class="left block" value="#{msg['details']}"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText class="left block" value="#{rem.detail}"></h:outputText>
                                </h:column>
                                <h:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">  
                                        <h:outputText class="right block" value="#{msg['delays']}"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText class="right block" value="#{rem.delay}"></h:outputText>
                                </h:column>
                            </h:dataTable>    
            </rich:dataGrid>
</rich:panel> 


.data-table{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.data-grid{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.image{
    padding: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: The datatable fills the entire cell of the grid, what is it that you want to align?

Comment: Each cell of the first dataGrid contains an other dataGrid at the top, and a dataTable at the bottom. I want to align all inner dataGrid to the top, and all datatable to the top.

Comment: You mean the grids and dataTables should be next to each other? A picture would really help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images. Yes, an inner dataGrid is next to (above) a dataTable (It's as if in the outer dataGrid we have a row of dataGrids and below a raw of dataTables).

Comment: You can link to a picture though. Grid above the table is the default, how do you want it to look?

Comment: I have added a picture. Inside the grid, I want each picture to be centered in the cell of datagrid.